# How to create multiple plots where each series is in a different figure?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

i am having trouble trying to figure out how to plot multiple figures in python.  I have two dataframes and in each dataframe i have two columns.  Hence, I want a total of 4 plots, maybe all in one row and 4 columns?  or all in 2 rows and 2 columns.  I tried the following trick:

```
    actuals = ['Acttemplow','acttemphi']
    fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=4,figsize=(12,4))
    for i,var in enumerate(actuals):
        ny_winter_dat[var].plot(ax=axes[i],title='ny winter ' + var)
        il_winter_dat[var].plot(ax=axes[i],title='illonois winter ' + var)
```

But upon implementing the above algo, i am getting plots of two series in two figures. and the other two figures are blank.    I am not getting different series in different boxes.  I tried changing nrows=2 and ncols=4 but still not able to figure it out.   can someone please help?  thanks

Comment: You may find solution in this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27447573/3581357

Answer (score 0):

axes is a ndarray of shape 1,4

your loop is putting :

- ny_winter_dat[Acttemplow] in axe #0
- il_winter_dat[Acttemplow] in axe #0
- ny_winter_dat[acttemphi] in axe #1
- il_winter_dat[acttemphi] in axe #1

you want :

- ny_winter_dat[Acttemplow] in axe #0
- il_winter_dat[Acttemplow] in axe #2
- ny_winter_dat[acttemphi] in axe #1
- il_winter_dat[acttemphi] in axe #3

`actuals = ['Acttemplow','acttemphi']
    fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=4,figsize=(12,4))
    for i,var in enumerate(actuals):
        ny_winter_dat[var].plot(ax=axes[i],title='ny winter ' + var)
        il_winter_dat[var].plot(ax=axes[i+2],title='illonois winter ' + var)`