# How to plot different plots on same page in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have plotted 10 plots but they are showing in different windows but I want to plot grid of separate plots of descent size on same page or within few pages.

Code that reproduces my condition is:

```
matrix=np.random.randint(0,100,(50,10))
df=pd.DataFrame(matrix)
df.columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']


f=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(50,1)))
f.columns=['f']

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,i],f)
    plt.show()
```

The desired output should look something like:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446455/pandas-subplots-in-a-loop.

Comment: You will have to use subplot and create a figure in order for this to render like you want.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html is really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `plt.subplot()` for this. [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)

With subplot, you can place multiple plots in a single figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Arguments to subplot are (# rows, # cols, index in grid)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
# Modify left plot here
plt.title("Left Plot")
plt.text(0.4, 0.4, "1", fontsize=50)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
# Modify right plot here
plt.title("Right Plot")
plt.text(0.4, 0.4, "2", fontsize=50)

plt.show()
```

This code produces:

[image: side by side plot]

Simply change the first two digits in the argument to `subplot` to increase the number of rows and columns in the grid.

For your application with 10 plots, you could do this:

```
# Increase figure size so plots are big
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 40))

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i+1)
    plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,i],f)

plt.show()
```

This will create a grid of plots with 5 rows and 2 columns.

Reference:

- https://showmecode.info/matplotlib/figure/side-by-side/

Comment: i tried this method earlier but got very small plots

Comment: You can increase the figure size with `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 40))`. This will make your figure 10 inches wide by 40 inches tall. @Razeun

Answer (score 0):

Will this give you a clue as to how to achieve your goal?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matrix = np.random.randint(0,100,(50,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
f = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(50,1)))
f.columns = ['f']
fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

axs[0,0].scatter(df.iloc[:,0],f)
axs[0,1].scatter(df.iloc[:,1],f)
axs[1,0].scatter(df.iloc[:,2],f)
axs[1,1].scatter(df.iloc[:,3],f)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

UPDATED FOR LOOP:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matrix = np.random.randint(0,100,(50,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
f = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(50,1)))
f.columns = ['f']

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

i = 0
for a in axs:
    for b in a:
        ax[a,b].scatter(df.iloc[:,i],f)
        i += 1

plt.show()
```

Comment: i have to do this via loop...how can i manage axis ?